# Best way to understand common fundamental distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have been following the online MIT statistics course, and one course was about some fundamental distributions.(https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading5c.pdf)

I read it a couple of times and did a lot of search online, but I still find it hard to fully grasp the idea of how to match different distributions to different real life scenarios.

For example, "Suppose we have a tape measure with markings at each millimeter. If we measure (to the nearest marking) the length of items that are roughly a meter long, the rounding error will uniformly distributed between -0.5 and 0.5 millimeters." I just cannot wrap my head around how it was determined that uniform distribution matches this case.

I'm wondering if there are some books/articles that give detailed and intuitive explanation of distributions and their real life applications?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, they seem to be implicitly assuming something about the distribution of lengths of objects to be measured. It does not seem crazy to model the rounding errors as being uniformly distributed, but we can't prove based on the given information that the model is accurate. (In fact it probably is not perfectly accurate.)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this myself, but I browsed it now and it seems very good. Though I'd want some more real life stuff there - I'll add to this if I find any.

(second day that the original link doesn't work, so I substitute yet another)
http://www.fysik.su.se/~walck/suf9601.pdf

As for your particular distribution: There are many slices of measurements, so it is practically random where the result lies around a certain millimeter mark. If you had a measure with 10 cm scale, then the depiction "roughly a meter long" would already work to make it somewhat skewed.

Quite obvious, but I add this anyway: with that 10 cm spaced measure, you would get the same distribution again if the results were roughly 100 meters long.

Comment: I am having problems opening the link in your answer. Can you check that it works properly? Ty

Comment: Strange - it was the link I fetched it with, and I checked after my answer that it worked. But indeed it didn't work now. Here is another link to the same content:
https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/2288328/mod_resource/content/1/Distribui%C3%A7%C3%B5es-Estat%C3%ADsticas.pdf

Comment: Great! I have saved it locally, will start reading soon. Thanks!